# Unknown server tag 'asp:UpdatePanel' only when doing Build or Publish

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, .net-3.5, ajaxcontroltoolkit

This ASP.NET web application was developed in VS2010 and I was asked among other things to upgrade the solution to 2012. When I did, I could no longer publish the project because of the error in subject plus the same error about `asp:UpdateProgress`. But the application runs fine when I start it from VS2012, including the page that uses those two controls!

A bit of history: initially the page was using MS AJAX controls, but at some point (Feb 2009) it was changed to use AjaxControlToolkit 3.5.60501 and the following line was added at the top of the ASCX file and the master page file:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="AJAX" %>
```

At the same time `asp:ScriptManager` control in the master page was replaced with

```
<AJAX:ToolkitScriptManager  ID="ScriptManager1" AsyncPostBackTimeout="180" runat="server"
    EnableScriptGlobalization="true" EnableScriptLocalization="true">
    <Services>
        <asp:ServiceReference Path="AutoComplete.asmx" InlineScript="true" />
    </Services>
</AJAX:ToolkitScriptManager>
```

Apparently `AJAX` tag prefix here replaced the `asp` tag prefix. But that does not seem to break functioning of the `UpdatePanel` and `UpdateProgress`. The project still publishes fine from VS2010. Publishing/building in VS2012 is the only thing which is broken now.

Do I need an updated version of AjaxControlToolkit or is the problem elsewhere?

Comment: You need to remove the old version of AjaxControlToolkit.dll from the references or just uninstall it via NuGet Packages.

Comment: @DinoMyte Just remove, nothing else? Can you elaborate please!?

Comment: There is probably a conflict with the references libraries related to AjaxControlToolkit.dll. Check the version of the dll using properties in VS and remove the old one from references folder in your web app or website app

Comment: Sorry, I still do not follow. I uninstalled the old version, downloaded the latest, ran the installer, copied the new DLL into the References of the project, re-added the reference and now I have tons of errors stating that AjaxControlToolkit is not declared. Can you provide the detailed instructions on how to get this working, not just a one-liner?